# What is focal scope?

Tags: javascript

I am reading a book on Javascript and it uses the word 'focal scope' but never states what it means. Example: "The interpreter's focal scope will move into the newly created scope"

It seems like they are using the notion of focal scope to refer to control flow. When I google 'focal scope Javascript' nothing really comes up. Is there anything more to this?

Comment: typo ("local") ?

Comment: I don't really know the answer, but perhaps mentioning which book it is would help.

Comment: SOme OCR failed I suppose.

Comment: Focal in the sense of camera? Zoomed out and zooming in as a scope is entered?

Comment: chopper, you might want to send an email to the author

Comment: @dystroy Yeah I may do that. Thanks anyways guys!

Comment: @chopperdrawlion4 You already saw here this isn't a widely accepted expression

Answer (score 1):

may be the author is using focal just like that.I mean in English it means:

```
relating to the center or most important part.
```

so basically he/she is trying to say that :

```
"The interpreter's main scope will move into the newly created scope"
```

focal is used more of a English word perhaps!!